# Generating set for submodule of free module over a PIR

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated, free-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative principal ideal ring (not necessarily a domain), $S \cong R^n$ a free $R$-module. We know that any submodule $M$ of $S$ has $m := \operatorname{length}_R(M) \leq n \cdot \operatorname{length}_R(R)=\operatorname{length}_R(S)$. Is it true that there exists $\{u_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ a basis of $S$ and scalars $d_1, \dots, d_m$ with $d_1 \mid d_2 \mid \dotsc \mid d_m$ such that $\{d_i u_i\}_{1\leq i \leq m}$ is a generating set for $M$? I think that this is true and an easy way to show it is simply by using the Smith normal form (which exists for general PIRs), is there something wrong with this reasoning? Is it true only when $R$ is a PID?

Comment: I've made some edits. (a) Are they OK? (b) Please clarify: Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, the edits are ok (I don't think the content changed, but thanks for improving the formatting) and I edited the question to clarify that the ring is commutative